# How to fix a JButton in JTable? Because After pressing the button is suspended in its last position in the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecelleditor

I have got a problem with `JTable` and `JButton`.
After pressing the button, is suspended in its last position in the table.
Try to run the code below.

Firs I open row "Open 4" and Close by button "Close 4".
After that if I Open row "Open 3" the button "4" is still there...

How to fix this?

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.EventObject;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import javax.swing.table.*;

    class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasValue, int row, int column) {
            DefaultTableModel model =((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel());
            if (model.getValueAt(row,0)!=null && column==0) { 
                String DATA= "Close "+(model.getValueAt(row,0)).toString();
                JButton b = new JButton(DATA);
                return b;
                }
            else return null;
            }
        }

    class MyEditor implements TableCellEditor {
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(final JTable table, Object value,
                                             boolean isSelected, final int row, int column){
            final DefaultTableModel model =((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel());    
            if (model.getValueAt(row,0)!=null && column==0 ){
                String text =model.getValueAt(row,0).toString();
                final JButton b = new JButton(text);
                ActionListener AKCJA = new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(model.getValueAt(row+1,0)==null)
                            while(model.getValueAt(row+1,0)==null)
                                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(row+1);                        
                        }
                    };
                    b.addActionListener(AKCJA);
                    return b;
                    } 
            else  return null;            
            } 
        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener cl) { }
        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener cl) { }
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject ev) { return true; }
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject ev) {return true;}
        public Object getCellEditorValue() { return null;}
        public boolean stopCellEditing() { return true;}
        public void cancelCellEditing() { }
        }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MyJpanel extends JPanel{
        public MyJpanel(){
            super(new GridLayout(1,0));
            final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();          
            model.addColumn("Col1");
            model.addColumn("Col2");          

            for(int kk=0;kk<8;kk++)
                model.addRow(new Object[]{kk, "Open "+kk});

            final JTable table = new JTable(model);   
            TableColumn td = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
            MyRenderer mojRenderer = new MyRenderer();
            td.setCellRenderer(mojRenderer);
            MyEditor mojEditor = new MyEditor();
            td.setCellEditor(mojEditor);

            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
                    new ListSelectionListener() {
                        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                            int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                            if(event.getValueIsAdjusting())
                                 if((model.getValueAt(viewRow,0))!=null)
                                     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                                         model.insertRow(viewRow+i+1,new Object[]{null, "b"});               
                            }
                        }         
                    );
            add(table );
            }
        }

    public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            final JFrame ramka=new JFrame("xxx");
            ramka.getContentPane().add(new MyJpanel());
            ramka.setSize(500,200);
            ramka.setVisible(true);
            ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: the editor implementation is invalid: it _must_ notify its listeners when it is terminated. Have a look at the source of DefaultCellEditor to get an idea of how-to do it. Also: a) never-ever create a new editing or rendering component in getXXComponent b) don't directly change the model in the editor, that's not its job c) learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0):

The solution is remove button in `Jtable` container by using for example `table.removeAll();` before button `ActionListener()`.

Very usefull to find problem was:
`Component[] Komponenty = table.getComponents()`;
You can print Array Komponenty and found components which you forgot to delete or hide;

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful :-) Unfortunately, the answer is comletely wrong (in that it is doctoring on symptoms instead od curing the desease)